# Generating new histogram within loop with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, pyspark

Here is code i've written to display a histogram of data :

```
from scipy.stats import norm  

rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["p1", "p2"])


for col in dataframe.columns :
    dataframe.toPandas()[col].plot(kind='hist', normed=True)
```

displays :

[image]

How can I generate a new histogram within the `for col.....` loop for each column of data instead of overlaying each column on same data point as is shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a new figure (or at least axis) each time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

for col in dataframe.columns:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    dataframe.toPandas()[col].plot(kind='hist', normed=True, ax=ax)
```